# Function field return type in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

In the following class I want to type the onPress method as a function which returns `void`. Is there a way to do that?

```
class Human {
  var onPress;

  Human({
    this.onPress,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identical to Remi’s declaration, there is a `VoidCallback` typedef already declared in Flutter.

So you could just declare it as:

```
VoidCallback onPress;
```

However, if you want to pass in parameters, you should setup your own typedefs.

Answer (score 15):

```
class Human {
  void Function() onPress;

  Human({
    this.onPress,
  });
}
```

or

```
typedef VoidFunction = void Function();

class Human {
  VoidFunction onPress;

  Human({
    this.onPress,
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, the OR  parts work nicely for custom return types. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`VoidCallback onPress` works but you can also use `Function onPress` too like this

```
class Human {
  Function onPress;

  Human({
    this.onPress,
  });
}
```